# org.json JsonObject.has() returning true for key that doesn't exist

Tags: java, google-app-engine, org.json

Edit - Resolved:
The issued turned out to be a combination of our logging code and how json.org handles the distinction between Javascript null and Javascript undefined.  Our logging code didn't print null values in objects, so although the json object I saw had no "invoice" field, the actual input had a null "invoice" field.  JSONObject's .has() method reported that there was an "invoice" field, but when I tried to access it, it's value was null so it wasn't possible to access it.  Replacing the .has() check with a .isNull() check (which considers both absent fields and null values) resolved the problem.

In my Google App Engine application, we parse webhook data in the form of json and go down different code paths depending on the presence of a certain key in the json object - if $.data.object.invoice exists we do some work, otherwise we don't.  However, when running in production, this detection seems to be broken.  I do a simple

```
jsonObject.getJSONObject("data").getJSONObject("object").has("invoice")
```

to check for the invoice key and sometimes this returns true even when the invoice key doesn't exist.  I came across this error because we do make use of the invoice value when it exists, and I was getting JSONExceptions trying to access it, even though it was protected by a has() check.  I added the following logging to ensure that I was doing everything correct:

```
boolean isAutomaticCharge = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data").getJSONObject("object").has("invoice");
boolean doesGettingStringWork;
try {
    jsonObject.getJSONObject("data").getJSONObject("object").getString("invoice");
    doesGettingStringWork = true;
}
catch (JSONException e) {
    doesGettingStringWork = false;
}
Logger.log("The value of automatic charge is: " + isAutomaticCharge);
Logger.log("Geting the invoice worked? " + doesGettingStringWork);
Logger.log(jsonObject.getJSONObject("data").getJSONObject("object").toString());
if (isAutomaticCharge) {
    handleFailedCharge(jsonObject);
}
else {
    //Manual Charge
}
```

And in production the following data resulted in isAutomaticCharge being true and doesGettingStringWork being false:

```
{
"id": "evt_16vC0s1WJGsEk3Qvnstmq6fa",
"object": "event",
"api_version": "2014-03-28",
"created": 1444678274,
"data": {
  "object": {
    "id": "ch_16vC0r1WJGsEk3Qv5rxezNQj",
    "object": "charge",
    "amount": 1900,
    "amount_refunded": 0,
    "captured": false,
    "card": {
      "id": "card_16vC0k1WJGsEk3Qvl9LLEt5K",
      "object": "card",
      "brand": "MasterCard",
      "country": "CA",
      "customer": "cus_79V0ZH6qFFA4K0",
      "cvc_check": "fail",
      "exp_month": 9,
      "exp_year": 2016,
      "fingerprint": "ifxs23sixYzpKant",
      "funding": "credit",
      "last4": "6912",
      "metadata": {},
      "name": "derek@footbole.com",
      "type": "MasterCard"
    },
    "created": 1444678273,
    "currency": "usd",
    "customer": "cus_79V0ZH6qFFA4K0",
    "failure_code": "card_declined",
    "failure_message": "Your card was declined.",
    "fraud_details": {},
    "livemode": true,
    "metadata": {},
    "paid": false,
    "refunded": false,
    "refunds": [],
    "source": {
      "id": "card_16vC0k1WJGsEk3Qvl9LLEt5K",
      "object": "card",
      "brand": "MasterCard",
      "country": "CA",
      "customer": "cus_79V0ZH6qFFA4K0",
      "cvc_check": "fail",
      "exp_month": 9,
      "exp_year": 2016,
      "fingerprint": "ifxs23sixYzpKant",
      "funding": "credit",
      "last4": "6912",
      "metadata": {},
      "name": "derek@footbole.com",
      "type": "MasterCard"
    },
    "status": "failed"
  }
},
"livemode": true,
"pending_webhooks": 2,
"request": "req_79V0v7433eb9hZ",
"type": "charge.failed"
}
```

When I run the code locally and feed it that json, it works as expected with isAutomaticCharge and doesGettingStringWork both being false.

I'm running version 20140107 of org.json.  I declare a new JSONObject for every request, so threading shouldn't be an issue.  Has anyone else had issues running org.json on Google App Engine?

Comment: Are you supplying your own version of [org.json](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java)?

Comment: Also, when you say "running the code locally", do you mean using a specific version of the App Engine SDK? Which command?